# download virtual directory from blob storage

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage

I want to download virtual directory from Azure blob storage. directory is present in container. I tried using `ColudBlobDirectory` API. but it doesn't have any method for downloading virtual directory.

```
for (ListBlobItem blobItem : container.listBlobs()) { 
    // If the item is a blob, a virtual directory. 
    if (blobItem instanceof CloudBlobDirectory) { 
        CloudBlobDirectory blob1 = (CloudBlobDirectory) blobItem; 
        System.out.println("\n Blob prefix:" + blob1.getPrefix()); 
    }
}
```

Comment: would recommend the code that you tried.

Comment: for (ListBlobItem blobItem : container.listBlobs()) {
                       // If the item is a blob, a virtual directory.
                       if (blobItem instanceof CloudBlobDirectory) {
                                    CloudBlobDirectory blob1 = (CloudBlobDirectory) blobItem;
                        
                        
                           System.out.println("\n Blob prefix:"+blob1.getPrefix());
                       
                        
                           
                       }     @Yogesh_D

Comment: Try to download items from directory one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @talex said, you can download blob file from directory one by one like this:

```
public static String destFilePath = "/path/to/directory/";

public static void main(String[] args)
        throws InvalidKeyException, URISyntaxException, StorageException, IOException {

    CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);
    CloudBlobClient serviceClient = account.createCloudBlobClient();
    CloudBlobContainer container = serviceClient.getContainerReference("mycontainer");

    for (ListBlobItem blobItem : container.listBlobs()) {

        // If the item is a blob, a virtual directory.
        if (blobItem instanceof CloudBlobDirectory) {

            CloudBlobDirectory blobDir = (CloudBlobDirectory) blobItem;
            downloadDirectory(blobDir);
        }
    }
}

public static void downloadDirectory(CloudBlobDirectory blobDir)
        throws IOException, StorageException, URISyntaxException {

    Files.createDirectories(Paths.get(destFilePath + blobDir.getPrefix()));

    for (ListBlobItem blobInDir : blobDir.listBlobs()) {

        if (blobInDir instanceof CloudBlockBlob) {
            CloudBlockBlob blob = (CloudBlockBlob) blobInDir;
            blob.downloadToFile(destFilePath + blob.getName());
        } else {
            downloadDirectory((CloudBlobDirectory) blobInDir);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If file is present inside subfolders then how to download that file @Aaron Chen